# What is the difference between using finders and actions to interact with a element?

Tags: ruby, capybara

When looking for a element is there any functional difference between:

```
find('someLocator').click()
```

and

```
click_link('someLocator')
```

Does the find method do a point in time inspection looking for the supplied element or does it wait for it to exist like most of the action methods??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click_link('someLocator') is implemented as  find(:link, 'someLocator').click so no there's no real difference, both will use Capybara's waiting behavior to look for the matching element